# DataTable with multiple and single selection

Tags: primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have a DataTable that displays information about executable applications. I have the following requirements:
 - Execute N applications by selecting N rows from the DataTable.
 - Modify information of a single Application by clicking the Update/Delete buttons in the last column of the DataTable.
I can do either the first or the second but having a really hard time doing them both.

```
<ui:include src="/dialogs/readTestcase.xhtml" />
...
<p:dataTable id="Testcase_DT" 
             var="Testcase" 
             value="#{testcaseProvider.testcases}" 
             rowKey="#{Testcase.testcaseId}" 
             selection="#{testcaseProvider.selectedTestcases}">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
              style="width: 15px; text-align: center;" />

    <p:column headerText="Actions">
        <p:commandButton id="UpdateTestcase_BTN"
                         value="Update"
                         oncomplete="PF('READ_TESTCASE').show();"
                         update=":ReadTestcase_DLG"
                         style="width: 100px; text-align: center;" />
    </p:column>
```

Right so my problem. I have multiple selection but in order to Update model information I need a single selection, so when I open up the READ_TESTCASE dialog it knows which object to query. What is the sophisticated way of handling this exact situation? Unfortunately I can't and not allowed to change on these requirements - I already tried but our client didn't want to hear about different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be to hard, you already have a multiple select semantics, so all the selected row in your model. To add the single row to model, without breaking what you already have, add a propertyListener to your command button

```
                 <p:commandButton id="UpdateTestcase_BTN"
                                     value="Update"
                                     oncomplete="PF('READ_TESTCASE').show();"
                                     update=":form:display"
                                     style="width: 100px; text-align: center;" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Testcase}" target="#{testcaseProvider.selectedTestcase}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

of course make sure that you have a selectedTestcase property in your backing bean, with getters and setters. Than the single row will be available in your dialog by referencing `#{testcaseProvider.selectedTestcase}`